# Targeting a html element but only on specified page

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using a shop CMS that allows me to apply a side menu for all product categories, let's call them Necklaces and Rings, that CMS also has an option to add "New" and "Promotions" to that side menu globally, however what I cannot do is specify where I want these "New" and "promotions" to be. For example I want them to be displayed in Rings category but not in Necklaces.

This is a rough sketch how the website is made:

```
   <div class="menu" id="side_menu">
  <ul class="standard">
     <li id="category_newstuff"><a href="/pl/c/Bizuteria/13" title="New">New</a></li>
     <li id="category_14"><a href="/pl/c/Collection/14" title="Collection1">Collection1</a>
     <li id="category_14"><a href="/pl/c/Collection/14" title="Collection2">Collection2</a>
     <li id="category_14"><a href="/pl/c/Collection/14" title="Collection3">Collection3</a>
     <li id="category_14"><a href="/pl/c/Collection/14" title="Collection4">Collection4</a>
     <li id="category_promotions"><a href="/pl/promotions" title="Promotions" class="promo">Promotions</a></li> 
</div>
```

What I want to achieve:

If the page is: rings.html then find "li id="category_newstuff" and apply "style="display"none">

I'm sorry if this is all gibberish lol.

Comment: what have you tried before asking SO? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class on your body tag. For example, the page you want to apply the style to, will have `<body class="with-style">` and in the css file, you can simply write **.with-style .category_newstuff { display: none; }**, or just find .with-style .category_newstuff via JS and hide it.

Comment: I sadly don't have any html for specific pages. It's all made with tpl files and just loads full page from those.